# MyList Video Player and Google API key

Tags: api, youtube

I'm using the stand-along MyList Youtube Playlist Player found [here](http://woosterwebdesign.com/mylist-video-player/)

I created my own Google browser API key found at console.developers.google.com.
The player works using the "sample" API key, but I get a 403 error when I use my own.
It seems pretty straight-forward.
After I got the key I added my website the the referrer list like this:  *.mydomain.com

Why the 403 error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable  the YouTube Data API from the developer's console.